# Finding two elements from list in ascending order of given number

Tags: list, for-loop, scheme, racket, void

I want to write a function that search two elements that a given number lies in between; (element1 < num < element2), and their position of first-element in list.

```
;; check x is between num-1 and num-2
(define (in-between? x num-1 num-2)
      (or (and (> num-1 x) (< num-2 x))
          (and (> num-2 x) (< num-1 x))))

;; the list elements values are always in ascending order
(define lst '(0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 6 7))

(define num 4.5)
;; expected-output=> 4.5 lies between element 4 and 5 of lst
;; '(4 5 12) ;; 12 is the position of first-element

;; output is list of 2 elements and the position of first-element
(define (find-interval u lst)
  (let* ([x (for/list ([a (drop-right lst 1)]
                       [b (cdr lst)]
                       [i (in-naturals)])
              (when (in-between? u a b)
                (list a b i)))])
    (car (filter list? x)))) ; to remove all #<void>
;; => '(4 5 12)
```

I have to use `(car (filter list? x))` to eliminate `#<void>` outputs in `x`, which is resulting 
`'(#<void>  #<void>  #<void>  #<void>  #<void>  #<void>  #<void>  #<void>  #<void>  #<void>  #<void>  #<void>  (4 5 12)  #<void>  #<void>  #<void>  #<void>  #<void>)`.

How do I prevent those `#<void>` in list coming out from `for/list` in `x`? It looks like there are unnecessarily longer steps in `find-interval` function. All the suggestions are welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the list is always in ascending order, the function can be defined with a simple tail-recursion which is compiled in an iterative way:

```
(define (find-interval el lst (pos 0))
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((null? (cdr lst)) '())
        ((>= (car lst) el) '())
        ((< (car lst) el (cadr lst)) (list (car lst) (cadr lst) pos))
        (else (find-interval el (cdr lst) (+ 1 pos)))))

(find-interval 4.5 '(0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 6 7))  ; => '(4 5 12)
```

Answer (score 1):

A named let can be used here to test through the list:

```
(define (find-interval u lst)
  (let loop ((idx 1))
    (if (= idx (length lst))
        #f
        (begin (let ((a (list-ref lst (sub1 idx)))
                     (b (list-ref lst idx)))
                 (if (in-between? u a b)
                     (list a b (sub1 idx))
                     (loop (add1 idx))))))))
```

It returns #f if such condition does not occur in the list.

Following version will produce a list of lists indicating multiple locations where the condition is satified:

```
(define (find-interval u lst)
  (let loop ((idx 1)
             (ol '()))
    (if (= idx (length lst))
        (reverse ol)
        (begin (let ((a (list-ref lst (sub1 idx)))
                     (b (list-ref lst idx)))
                 (if (in-between? u a b)
                     (loop (add1 idx) (cons (list a b (sub1 idx)) ol))
                     (loop (add1 idx) ol)))))))

(find-interval 4.5 '(0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 6 7 4 6))
; => '((4 5 12) (7 4 18) (4 6 19))
```

The input list need not have items in a sorted order in either of above functions.